# Cannot show data php debug bar in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Debug is set to true, why can I not see the laravel debug bar?

`APP_DEBUG=true`
`APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug`

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4opeI.png)

Comment: Have You install 
barryvdh/laravel-debugbar?

Comment: @RajenTrivedi I have it installed already `"barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.4"`

Answer (score 0):

**In config/debugbar.php, change 'enabled' property.** set enabled property to true.

```
'enabled' => true,
```

Comment: I added but it still doesn't work @Rajen Trivedi

Comment: Don't have to add, you just first search & if its false make it true.